# Pasar variables de HTML por javascript c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tengo una vista que debe mandar 2 values a un controlador, el primero que es el value de un select que funciona bien y se trae el valor y el segundo que es el rut de un trabajador, pero para este ultimo estoy utilizando `@item.rutTra.ToString()` y no logro pasarlo por la url.

Esta es la vista:

```
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                N°
            </th>
            <th>
                RUT
            </th>
            <th>
                Nombre
            </th>
            <th>
                Fecha Pago
            </th>
            <th>
                Detalles
            </th>
        </tr>


        @{
            int i = 0;
        }
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            i++;
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @i
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label id="rutid">@item.rutTra.ToString()</label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    @item.nombre
                </td>

                <td>
                    @item.fechaPago.ToShortDateString()
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("PDF", "VistaPDF")



                </td>
            </tr>


        }
    </table>
```

El script que manda los values:

```
    <script>
                (function () {
                    $('a').on('click', function (e) {
                        var $a = $(this);
                        var url = $a.prop('href').split("?")[0];

                        var parametro = {
                            tipo: $('#tpago').val()
                        };

                        var parametro1 = {
                            rutid: $('#rutid').val()
                        };

                        $a.prop('href', url + "?" + $.param(parametro) + "&&" + $.param(parametro1));
                    });
                })();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error (al menos uno) está en:

```
rutid: $('#rutid').val()
```

Eso sirve para inputs, pero tu rutid es un label. Si lo cambias por esto debería funcionar. Al menos recuperar el valor del label.

```
rutid: $('#rutid').text()
```

Comment: Te olvidas del foreach. Se crearán múltiples elementos con `id="rutid"`. Op debe utilizar un `for (int i =0; i<Model.Count;i++)`  para crear esos elementos dinámicamente con `<label id="@string.Format("rutid[{0}]",i)">@Model[i].rutTra.ToString()</label>`. Luego, debe lidiar con obtener todos esos elementos mediante jQuery.

Comment: Era lo que me estaba fallando, muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)

Comment: Si, tiene razón Arriel. No repitas ids o te dará problemas ya que se supone que deben ser únicos. Utiliza mejor una clase y luego el foreach del selector de clase $(".clase") por ejemplo.